# What is the condition that the following equation has four real roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> What are the conditions that the following equation has four real roots? (Tick all that apply)
> $$ (a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1)(a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2) = 0$$
> **a**. $c_1c_2 > 0$
>
> **b**. $a_1c_2 < 0$
>
> **c**. $a_2c_1 < 0$

**My Attempt**: For the equation to have four real roots, both the equations should have two real roots each. From their discriminants, this gives us
$$b_1^2 - 4a_1c_1 > 0 \text{  and  } b_2^2 - 4a_2c_2 > 0$$

I could not move past this step or use this step to derive any of the expressions mentioned.

Comment: It is not utterly clear whether the multiplicity of the roots is counted. If not, we also have to guarantee that there are no multiple roots.

Comment: In fact, if we allow $0$ to be a multiple-root, $c_1=c_2=0$ is possible which means that none of the conditions is necessary.

Comment: Take $b_1=b_2=0$. For $(a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2)=(-1,1,-1,4)$ satisfying $c_1c_2\gt 0, a_1c_2\lt 0$ and $a_2c_1\lt 0$, the roots are $x=\pm 1,\pm 2$. The roots are $x=\pm 1,\pm i$ for $(a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2)=(1,1,-1,1)$ satisfying $c_1c_2\gt 0$, for $(a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2)=(-1,-1,-1,1)$ satisfying $a_1c_2\lt 0$, and for $(a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2)=(-1,1,-1,-1)$ satisfying $a_2c_1\lt 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient if
$a_1c_1 < 0$
and
$a_2c_2< 0$.

If all 3 conditions hold then,
multiplying the first and second
$a_1c_1c_2^2 < 0$
so
$a_1c_1 < 0$.

Similarly, multiplying the first and third,
$a_2c_2c_1^2 < 0$
so
$a_2c_2< 0$.

Therefore if all three conditions hold there are four real roots.
The roots may not all be different depending on the coefficients.